# How to fetch corresponding value present under JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a JSON as shown below

```
[
    {
        "vendor_id": "5000819028",
        "vendor_name": "Test 01"
    },
    {
        "vendor_id": "5000823900",
        "vendor_name": "Test 03"
    }
]
```

I have got the vendor_name , for example Test 03

How can i fetch the corresponding vendor_id .

I have done this way , its working fine

```
var json = [
    {
        "vendor_id": "5000819028",
        "vendor_name": "Test 01"
    },
    {
        "vendor_id": "5000823900",
        "vendor_name": "Test 03"
    }
];

var vendorname = 'Test 03';

var result = '';

for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
{

    if(json[i].vendor_name===vendorname)
    {
        result = json[i].vendor_id ;
    }

}

alert(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10nh59f4/3/

But is there any other better way of doing it ??

Comment: You can use _.filter from Array, and $.grep from jQuery like so http://jsfiddle.net/10nh59f4/5/

Comment: Thanks , but in case if a wrong vendorname (which is not in array is given ) its throwing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vendor_id' of undefined , please let me know how to handle this .

Comment: updated example http://jsfiddle.net/10nh59f4/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with a slightly tiddy approach:

```
var result = null;
var vendername = 'Test 03';
json.some(function(item) {
    if ( item.vendor_name == vendername ) {
        result = item;
        return true;
    }
});
```

or using underscore / lodash:

```
var result = _.find(json, function(item) {
    return item.vender_name == vendername;
});
```

---

You could also use `filter` but this will not stop until all items is procesed:

```
var results = json.filter(function(item) {
    return item.vender_name == vendername;
});

// results is an Array, to get the first item use [0]:
var result = results[0];
```